# Regex looking for a base word (snmp-server) then it needs to have all three (group view and host)

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regex that searches a config file for snmp-server which needs to have a group a view and a host
so far i tried

```
snmp-server(group)(view)(host)
(^snmp-server group)(^snmp-server view)(^snmp-server host)
```

this one pull all three put it only looks for 1 of the three

```
snmp-server(group)|(view)|(host)
```

An example

This would pass

```
snmp-server group 
snmp-server view 
snmp-server enable 
snmp-server host
```

This would fail

```
snmp-server group 
snmp-server enable 
snmp-server host
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex:

```
(^snmp-server group).*(^snmp-server view).*(^snmp-server host)
```

Make sure to enable multiline AND single-line mode appropriate to whatever regex parser this is running in.

- [Match demo](https://regex101.com/r/z0MZvQ/1)
- [No match demo](https://regex101.com/r/YBE8xa/1)

---

EDIT: The following regex is more flexible w.r.t. the order and makes use of [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=.*^snmp-server group)(?=.*^snmp-server view)(?=.*^snmp-server host)
```

- [Match demo](https://regex101.com/r/uIq6MK/1)
- [No match demo](https://regex101.com/r/KktLDk/1)

Comment: I tried this one before and it didn't work.  All I needed was single line and multi line.  Thank you

Comment: @anubhava Yes it does, thank you for pointing it out. Please check the update.

Answer (score 2):

With capture group and back-references, you may use this regex:

```sh
\A(snmp-server)\s+(group|view|host)\n(?:.+\n)*?\1\s+(?!\2)(group|view|host)\n(?:.+\n)*?\1\s+(?!\2|\3)(group|view|host)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/79zgqJ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\A`: Start
- `(snmp-server)`: Match and group `snmp-server` in capture group #1
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(group|view|host)`: Match given 3 words and capture in group #2
- `\n(?:.+\n)*?`: Match line break followed by 0 or more lines (lazy)
- `\1\s+`: Using back-reference match `snmp-server` followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `(?!\2)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't match what we captured in group #2
- `(group|view|host)`: Match given 3 words and capture in group #3
- `\n(?:.+\n)*?`: Match line break followed by 0 or more lines (lazy)
- `\1\s+`: Using back-reference match `snmp-server` followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `(?!\2|\3)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't match what we captured in group #2 and group #3
- `(group|view|host)`: Match given 3 words and capture in group #4

Comment: Thank you for your attempt .  It does work, however it is extremely complex.  I appreciate you breaking it down for me.

Comment: Yes it is complex because I didn't assume that order of group, view and host lines would be fixed